# How to load a transparent html into a webview with a background

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I am loading an html page into a web view, the html page has GREY as the background color and the web view has a background image. When i load the html page into the web view i want the image to be visible with the html background transparent. How would i make the GREY color a transparent so that the image is visible.

Please see my html page code below and do help me pls

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org >
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<title>html page</title>

<style type="text/css">
    .show
    {
        display: inline;
    }
    .hide
    {
        display: none;
    }
    body.class
    {
        background: #444;
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana, Arial;
        opacity:0.4;
        color: #FFF;
        margin: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
        width: auto;
    }
    h1
    {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 25px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
    h2
    {
        font-size: 36px;
        margin: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .author-pic
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    p
    {
        line-height: 17px;
    }
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi just check below simple code you will get idea that how you need to insert value in your class for the various browser

```
 body.class {
    /* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
    /* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
    width: 100%; 

    /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
    /* ...but not required as filter works too */
    /* should come BEFORE filter */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

    /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
    /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);

    /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
    -moz-opacity:0.5;

    /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

    /* Modern!
    /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
    /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to alter the HTML as it is received, this example uses JSoup (mostly because I have it in my Downloaded-files folder).

```
public class SomeSortOfActivityNameGoesHere extends Activity {
    static final int TIMEOUT = 30000;
    WebView mView;
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> mLoad;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mView = new WebView(this);
        mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.addView(mView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        setContentView(layout);
        mLoad = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>() {
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), TIMEOUT);
                    Element body = doc.select("body").first();
                    body.attr("style", "background-color: transparent");
                    return new String[]{doc.baseUri(), doc.outerHtml(), "text/html", null, null};
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    mView.loadDataWithBaseURL(result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4]);
                    // Note: This is more or less required to be called again here.
                    mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                } else {
                    // Fancy error handling goes here
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

This example should load the stackoverflow.com page and turn it translucent and allow the red color in the LinearLayout holding the WebView to "shine through". Should work on ICS at least.

Comment: Jens thanks for helping but how would i modify my html page can you suggest pls

Comment: You'd need to include more of your HTML document in that case. The example I supplied would find the <body> tag in your HTML document and set a transparent style on it.